# Why might the Emacs "downcase" function refuse to do downcasing?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write simple Emacs function to convert ids between C style ones and camelCase ones (i.e. c_style <-> cStyle). But for some reason, Emacs built in `downcase` function leaves the word intact. `M-x downcase-word` works fine so I completely lost. Any ideas are welcome.

```
(defun toggle-id-style ()
  "Toggle between C-style ids and camel Case ones (i.e. c_style_id -> cStyleId and  back)."
  (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (progn
        (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9_]" nil t)
          (let ((end (point))
            (case-fold-search nil))
            (progn
              (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9_]" nil t)
              (let* ((cstyle (if (string-match "_" (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) end)) t nil))
                     (regexp (if cstyle "_\\(\\w+\\)" "\\([A-Z][a-z0-9]+\\)") )
                     (func (if cstyle 'capitalize (lambda (s) (concat "_" (downcase s) ) ))))
             (progn
                   (while (re-search-forward regexp end t)
                     (replace-match (funcall func (match-string 1)) nil nil)))))))))

;;M-x replace-regexp _\(\w+\) -> \,(capitalize \1) ;; c_style -> cStyle
;;M-x replace-regexp \([A-Z][a-z0-9]+\) -> _\,(downcase \1) ;;cStyle -> c_style
```

It works fine if I convert `c_style` but when I'm trying to convert `cStyle` I got `c_Style` as result. Yes, I've checked that this is due to `downcase` behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the second argument to `replace-match`. From the documentation:

> ```
> If second arg fixedcase is non-nil, do not alter case of replacement text.
> Otherwise maybe capitalize the whole text, or maybe just word initials,
> based on the replaced text.
> If the replaced text has only capital letters
> and has at least one multiletter word, convert newtext to all caps.
> Otherwise if all words are capitalized in the replaced text,
> capitalize each word in newtext.
> ```

You're passing `nil` for the `fixedcase` argument, which causes `replace-match` to capitalize the replacement when the text being replaced is capitalized.  Pass `t` instead and this bit of the code will work.

I have two general comments about your code.

1. All of your uses of `progn` are unnecessary. The body of `save-excursion` is an implicit `progn` and so are the bodies of `let` and `let*`.
2. You search forwards and then backwards to try to find the bounds of the symbol underneath point. Emacs already has a `thingatpt` library to find things at or near the point.  In your case you can just call `(bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)` which returns a cons cell `(START . END)` giving the start and end positions of the symbol that was found.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the second arg of replace-match to be t instead of nil.